# How can I use python to get the longitude and latitude from a GooglePlaceSearchResult?

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am using a the Google Places Api to check the location of certain schools, and trying to use that location to confirm that two results are in the same place. Currently, I have this:

```
    API_KEY = 'My_API_Key'
    gp = gop.GooglePlaces(API_KEY)
    check = gp.text_search(query= kw[0], types= 'school|university')
    for p in possible_matches:
        possible = gp.text_search(query= p[1], types= 'school|university')
        test = [i for i in check.places if i in possible.places]
        print test
        if test != []:
            print "Same Place."
            break
```

The result when I call this code is

```
[<Place name="1885 Miramonte Ave", lat=37.369, lng=-122.08463>]
[]
[<Place name="2400 E Lake Ave", lat=36.9401097, lng=-121.7403299>]
[]
[<Place name="2000 Lawrence Ct", lat=37.358898, lng=-121.9952864>]
[]
[<Place name="2001 37th Ave", lat=37.74806950000001, lng=-122.4959313>]
```

How can I use Python to take the get the latitude and longitude from this result?

Comment: So it seems above `i` in the list comprehensions are instances of the `Place` class - whatever that is - the hint in above print output is to try `test = [(i.name, i.lat, i.lng) for i in check.places if i in possible.places]` instead ... which in the first case should give something like `[('1885 Miramonte Ave', 37.369, -122.08463)]`  ...

Comment: You should not be sharing your API key to the public - it may get misused!

Comment: Thanks Steve! My bad!

Comment: @Dilettant, I tried your suggestion, and it just returned blank lists.